# CoffeeScript specific accessor for class variables

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I realize that in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) `@someVar` is [translated](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) to `this.someVar`. Is there any similar operator which can be used to access class members? Consider the following example:

```coffee
class @SleepTracking
  @sleepQualities = ["none", "nervous", "quiet"]
  @timeFormat = "H:mm:ssZ"

  constructor: (value) ->
    # Initialization

  doSomething: ->
    # How to access timeFormat except using SleepTracking.timeFormat ?
```

Is there any other way to access `timeFormat` inside the class functions except `SleepTracking.timeFormat`?

**Update:**

The variables are defined using `@` so it would be possible to use them  out of class's scope without instantiating the class. For example:

```coffee
someFunction = () ->
  validQuality = SleepTracking.sleepQualities
  # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SleepTracking
  @sleepQualities = ["none", "nervous", "quiet"]
  @timeFormat = "H:mm:ssZ"

  constructor: (value) ->
    @timeFormat = SleepTracking.timeFormat

  doSomething: ->
    @timeFormat

st = new SleepTracking()

console.log SleepTracking.timeFormat
console.log st.doSomething()
```

Closest I can see is that you do something like this.  It gives you static access to the variables but then also allows use within the function of an instantiated class.  It is a bit rubbish that you have to set up the constructor property though :(

Go to http://coffeescript.org/ and the `Try Coffeescript` tab to give it a go.

Comment: I also want to use the variable outside the class, so dropping `@` really does not help me!

Comment: Do you need them as static variables? If you're newing up the class where you're using it you'll be able to access them from outside using `sleepTracking.timeFormat`

Comment: Since I'm not the class's scope, I suppose I do. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort here. But my Idea was to be able to use those variables without instantiating the class. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Right, I've updated my answer, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get at the "class":

> Returns a reference to the `Object` function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name.

So given something like this:

```
class C
    m: -> ...
```

you could look at `@constructor` inside `m` and get `C`. Note that this properly handles subclassing so this:

```
class C
    @cp = 11
    m: -> console.log(@constructor.cp)
class D extends C
    @cp = 23
class E extends C

(new C).m()
(new D).m()
(new E).m()
```

dumps 11, 23, and 11 into the console ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SwfLq/)).

In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
doSomething: ->
    format = @constructor.timeFormat
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to access timeFormat inside the class functions except `SleepTracking.timeFormat`?

I don't think so. However, you might use class-scoped aliases for them:

```
class @SleepTracking
  sleepQuals = @sleepQualities = ["none", "nervous", "quiet"]
  @timeFormat = "H:mm:ssZ"
  consts = @

  doSomething: ->
    SleepTracking.timeFormat === consts.timeFormat
    SleepTracking.sleepQualities === sleepQauls
```

The variable (`sleepQuals`) approach is best fitting for constants (or constant references to mutable objects/arrays), while the class name alias (`consts`) is nothing but name shortening and easing the renaming of the class. Yet I think just writing `SleepTracking` out is the least confusing.